# When working with Rails, CoffeeScript and Backbone.js, is the preferred model attribute naming convention "underscored"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Most generic CoffeeScript/Backbone.js examples use attribute names like `someFlag`, however Rails prefers/requires `some_flag`.

Is anyone aware of discussion on the topic or a style guide that takes this into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

I follow the convention of the server technology for my Backbone models.

For example, in my Rails applications, I set attributes using underscore names like `some_value`, and in my .NET applications I set attributes using capitalized names like `SomeValue`.

This makes it easier to integrate everything on the back-end. It's a minor inconvenience to remember to do this in the client side code, but once I'm deep in to a project, it becomes habit for that project.

The ease of the back-end integration is well worth the minor effort to use the convention that the server wants, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

"There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."

-- Phil Karlton

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html